# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$HasOptions.class

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, google-play-services

I am unable to build my cordova project for android.

The plugins installed are

```
com.bez4pieci.cookies 0.0.1 "Cookies"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-cookieemperor 1.0.0 "CookieEmperor"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.2.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 2.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.3 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.6.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 2.3.17 "Diagnostic"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.10 "StatusBar"
org.chromium.common 1.0.6 "Chrome Apps Common Utils"
org.ck12.identity 1.2.1 "Google Play Identity API"
```

The dependencies added in build.gradle are as follows.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

I also have a zip file called `google-play-services.zip` in libs folder which is included in compile filetree

cordova version 7.0.1

Comment: Can you mention during which gradle task of the build process did it fail ? Was it `packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `google-play-services.zip` because it will create duplicacy issue with `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"`

if you want more goole play service feature you can add it explicitly in `build.gradle` like this :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
```

and add  `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle` like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side, the error was from the combination between cordova platform `android@6.3.0` and cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-compat` which is deprecated and creates issues on build with android@6.3.0+.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: You can also update the compat plugin to 1.2.0 and it will build. (BTW, nice share!)